Issue with Regex Pattern (split string with characters & numbers) in Java
Issue: The string split using Regex pattern is not working as per expectation
String: TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) 11.97 DR11.97 DR0.00 CR
Required Output: String Array as below

TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES)
11.97 DR
11.97 DR
0.00 CR

Regex Pattern used: (?<=\d{1,}.\d{2} (DR|CR))
Output (using the above regex):

TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) 11.97 DR
11.97 DR
0.00 CR

As seen from the above, the string is not getting split at the first 11.97 DR. Hope the issue faced is clear, any pointers on what I need to change to get the split as per my need will help.
Code:
String text = "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) 11.97 DR11.97 DR0.00 CR";
String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\d{1,}\.\d{2} (DR|CR))");
System.out.println(parts);

Added:
Some of the other lines which needs to be split using regex

text1 = "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (SHIP CHARGE) 192.57 DR192.57 DR0.00
CR"
text2 = "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (DEPOT TAX) 520.00 DR520.00 DR0.00
CR"
text3 = "IGST* RATE:18% AMOUNT (RS.) 401.19 DR401.19 DR0.00 CR"


Hey, did you try using the libraries like "import java.util.regex.Matcher" and
"import java.util.regex.Pattern"?
We can use the regex pattern to match any number (integer or decimal) followed by either "DR" or "CR."
Then, we can split the string at each of these patterns so we capture each "number + DR/CR" as a distinct part.
However, the solution will take more than three lines. Let us know if you need the complete implementation.

posted code is not valid Java (e.g. \d or \.) what else are we missing; or was changed by non-OP? --- you can also try with text.splitWithDelimiters("\\d+\\.\\d{2} (DR|CR)",0) but it needs some trimming

Hello iCoder, please, edit your question, and add the different possible entries.

I've updated my answer with the new string cases

split is the wrong tool to use for this.  If you just use Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d{2} [DC]R").matcher(text) and call the matcher’s find method repeatedly, you won’t need complex look-aheads and look-behinds.

Your regex is splitting for each occurrence of DR or CR preceded by a number with two decimals. This is why TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) is included in your first result.
You could add the case "... or split for any white space preceded by a parenthesis". It seems in fact that the pattern of your strings is in the form of <some text> (<some text in parenthesis>) <sequence of number followed by DR or CR>.
Your regex could be written like this:
((?<=\))\s*|(?<=\d{1,}\.\d{2} (DR|CR)))

Here is also a sample that you can test on OneCompiler.
String[] tests = {
        "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) 11.97 DR11.97 DR0.00 CR",
        "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (SHIP CHARGE) 192.57 DR192.57 DR0.00 CR",
        "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (DEPOT TAX) 520.00 DR520.00 DR0.00 CR",
        "IGST* RATE:18% AMOUNT (RS.) 401.19 DR401.19 DR0.00 CR"
};

for (String test: tests){
    String[] parts = test.split("((?<=\\))\\s*|(?<=\\d{1,}\\.\\d{2} (DR|CR)))");
    Arrays.stream(parts).forEach(System.out::println);
}


You are missing another position to split on, which is the space at the end of  (FEES) 
Instead of using a capture group (DR|CR) you can use a character class [DC]R and in the lookbehind you don't have to match 1 or more digits \d{1,} but just matching a digit \d would also suffice.
As there seems to be a digit following the parts you want to split on, you can assert a digit to the right:
(?<=\d\.\d{2} [DC]R|\))\h*(?=\d)


(?<= Positive lookbehind, assert that directly to the left is

\d\.\d{2} [DC]R Match a digit . 2 digits and either DR or CR
| Or
\) Match )


) Close the lookbehind
\h* Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
(?=\d) Positive lookahead, assert a digit to the right

See a regex demo and a Java demo.
Example
String regex = "(?<=\\d\\.\\d{2} [DC]R|\\))\\h*(?=\\d)";
String s = "TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES) 11.97 DR11.97 DR0.00 CR";
String[] parts = s.split(regex);

for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}

Output
TAXABLE VALUE OF SUPPLY (FEES)
11.97 DR
11.97 DR
0.00 CR

Instead of splitting you could also match the parts that you want using an alternation, where the alternative starts with \S to start the match with a non whitespace character to prevent matching empty strings:
\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h*[DC]R|\S.*?(?=\h*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h*[DC]R)

See another regex demo and a Java demo
